# function won't return files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my `index.js`:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Tester from "./Tester.js"

ReactDOM.render(<Tester />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

This is my `Apps.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

function Apps(props) {
console.log(props.name)

    return( 
    <div>
        <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>
    </div>
    )
  }

export default Apps
```

This is my `idNum.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

function idNum(props) {
console.log(props.ids)

    return( 
        <h1>Hello, {props.ids}</h1>

    )
  }

export default idNum
```

This is my `Tester.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import idNum from './idNum.js';
import Apps from './Apps.js';
import phoneNumber from './phoneNumber.js';

function Tester(props) {
    console.log(props.name)
    return (
        <div>
            <Apps name ="Hailey"/>
            <idNum id = "3" />
            <phoneNumber Integer ="88877738492"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
  
 
ReactDOM.render(
    <Tester
      name ={Apps}
      id ={idNum}
      number ={phoneNumber}
    />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );

  export default Tester
```

This is my `phoneNumber.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

function phoneNumber(props) {
console.log(props.nums)

    return( 
    <div>
        <h1>Hello, {props.nums}</h1>
    </div>
    )
  }

export default phoneNumber
```

Thank you! I'm not sure why `<idNum id = "3" /> <phoneNumber Integer ="88877738492"/>`
won't run while
`<Apps/>` can

Comment: components name should be capitalized.

Comment: doesn't make sence to do `ReactDOM.render` in `Tester.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a codesandbox with a few fixes:

- Components name and files in PascalCase
- Props name fixed
- A single render function in index.js

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-wing-ucjsn

Comment: Thank you, I forgot there should only be one ReactDOM and I did not know that Index is was the one that should take in value.                                                                         
This is a bit of a random question, but let's say I wanted to specify that the user input for 'idNum' should be an integer, Is there a way to do that with React?

Comment: @Paige https://github.com/facebook/prop-types#prop-types-

Comment: @Paige as jharris711 said, you can use prop-types or you can even use typescript (i like it more, it may be a little hard if you're starting but it will pay off in the long run). About the values you can pass them from where you want,that was just an example, depends on what you want to do